# How show only a view of an interface in java

Tags: java, view, interface, typechecking

Is it possible to show only a particular view of an interface or approximate this behavior in Java? For example:

```
public interface SecureDevice
{
   bool connectWith( SecureDevice d ); // visible to people who have a SecureDevice object
   bool connectWith( SecureDevice d, Authentication a ); // somehow only visible to classes with permission
}
```

I would like users of the SecureDevice interface to have no idea that an authentication needs to occur for the interaction to occur or even that the class Authentication exists. They don't need to know the details. They only need to know that the interaction either happened or didn't. For example, a user who obtained two SecureDevice objects might try this:

```
public void establishConnection(SecureDevice d1, SecureDevice d2 )
{

    Connector c = new Connector();

    if( false == d1.connectWith( d2 ) )
    {
        System.out.println("Couldn't connect to directly");
    }
    else if ( false == c.connect( d1, d2 ) )
    {
        System.out.println("Couldn't connect using Connector.");
    }
 }
```

but I might define a class like this:

```
public class Computer implements SecureDevice
{
    private Authentication auth;

    public bool connectWith( SecureDevice d )
    {
        return d.connectWith(d, auth);
    }

    private? bool connectWith(SecureDevice d, Authorization a)
    {
        // check the authorization, do whatever it takes to connect, etc.
    }
}
```

or similarly

```
public class Connector 
{
    private Authentication myAuth;

    public bool connect(SecureDevice a, SecureDevice b)
    {
        a.connectWith(b, myAuth);
    }

}
```

This example seems akin friends in C++, however I feel like it is slightly different. I don't want to give special permission to use a method.

I would like to have two interfaces as part of SecureDevice:

```
   public interface SecureDevice
   {
       public interface UserView
       {
           connectWith(SecureDevice d);
       }

       public interface LibraryView
       {
           connectwith(SecureDevice d, Authentication a);
       }
    }
```

If there really were two separate interfaces, I would have to cast between them when I wanted to use the other interface, and I wouldn't be able to gurantee that an object implementing one actually implemented the other, so I'd have to do runtime type checking.

**So to boil it down, I just want to present a simple interface to the user with only the methods he needs, and none of the business he doesn't need. How can I do (or approximate) this?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No. If you must present an interface without authentication, then that's what needs to be in that interface.

You could extend the interface, but you end up with a similar problem.

Another option would be to accept an implementation of something that does the real work, the construction of which contains the implementation details, *very* roughly:

public interface SecurableDevice {
    public boolean connectWith(Connector);
}

public class SecurableConnector implements Connecter {
    public SecurableDeviceConnector(SecureDevice sd) { ... }
    public void connectWith(d1) { ... }
}

public class SecurableDeviceConnector implements Connector {
    public SecurableDeviceConnector(SecureDevice sd, Authorization a) { ... }
    public void connectWith(d1) { ... }
}

The connection establishment is moved out of the SecurableDevice; the device calls connectWith, and it's handled there.

The Connector implementations can be provided to only the users that need them.

Comment: @user487100 I don't know what you mean.

Comment: @user487100 Oh, I get it--no no, I meant that as the summary of my answer, not that your question was too long.

Answer (score 1):

In Java you can't control access to individual methods using a plain interface. On the other hand, you *can* control access to methods in an EJB interface, where only users with the authorized roles can invoke a method - surely, every client class will *see* the exposed methods, but only authorized users will be able to invoke them successfully